# chef upgrade to 0.10: missing file libgecodeminimodel.so in dep_selector gem

Tags: chef-infra

I followed [the general doc](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Upgrading+Chef+0.9.x+to+Chef+0.10.x) to upgrade chef-server, but it fails to start after the upgrade because it can't find the gecode library file libgecodeminimodel.so.

This file exists from when I installed gecode 3.7.1, so it seems like a include path just needs to be set for the dep_selector gem.  I've tried re-installing the gem, but that didn't fix the issue.

Here's the error:

```
 /home/chef/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@chef_server/gems/dep_selector-0.0.8/lib/dep_gecode.so: libgecodeminimodel.so.30: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /home/chef/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@chef_server/gems/dep_selector-0.0.8/lib/dep_gecode.so (LoadError)
```

Here's where the files are:

```
 dizzy dep_selector-0.0.8 # ls -l      /home/chef/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@chef_server/gems/dep_selector-0.0.8/lib/dep_gecode.so
 -rwxr-xr-x 1 chef chef 485222 2012-02-19 23:12 /home/chef/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@chef_server/gems/dep_selector-0.0.8/lib/dep_gecode.so
 dizzy dep_selector-0.0.8 # ls -l /usr/local/lib/libgecodeminimodel.so*
 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      26 2012-02-19 22:24 /usr/local/lib/libgecodeminimodel.so -> libgecodeminimodel.so.30.0
 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      26 2012-02-19 22:24 /usr/local/lib/libgecodeminimodel.so.30 -> libgecodeminimodel.so.30.0
 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1194016 2012-02-19 22:24 /usr/local/lib/libgecodeminimodel.so.30.0
```

This issue seems to be old, because it's come up before ( http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.sysutils.chef.user/923 ) but I don't have the option of installing libgecode-dev from a repo, as I'm on an old FC11 box.

The instructions are provided for installing gecode from source, but there's something missing for me.  All thoughts and suggestions are appreciated, as our chef-server is clearly down right now.

Comment: Did you add /usr/local/lib to LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not happy with this solution, but I ended up rolling an rpm for gecode that installed into /usr instead of /usr/local.  This seems to have solved the issue.

You could likely also install from the tar directly into /usr, but that's against general file system structure, and I wouldn't recommend it.